# Is it possible to declare a Global <input> variable that gets used for all forms?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am wondering if there is a way to declare a Global HTML- tag, that gets submittet with each form that gets called.

I mean something in the way like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="200">
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  #Some Form-Stuff
</form>
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  #Some more Form-Stuff
</form>
```

And in both of these Forms, when a Submit is being made, there is supposed to be the Global hidden Input-Tag that gets delivered with the rest.

I already tried it and it didnt work, but I wonder if there is just something that is missing or if there is a similar or better way to accomplish this.

Would appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**

What I want in my current Project is to let the User `<SELECT>` an option that represents like an Folder in which there will be displayed data that is inside that folder.

I dont want the User to have to Select the Folder again after each click and the folder has to be submitted every time to the php-script so that it can handle data accordingly to the folder selected.

My Question in this case however still remains on wether you can or cannot make a `<input>` tag global or not, if it´s permanent or not doesnt matter.

Comment: if the value never gets changed, you can use as a session variable.

Comment: Can you not just echo a <input type=hidden> tag in each form?  Do you have an insane number of forms?  What is your concern?

Comment: Input tags can't be made global. They should be included with forms

Comment: What you are looking for is either a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). For both cases the value is available in all pages after it is set (not just in the forms).

Comment: Man, why the downvote after all this time? I was just reaching 100 rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either include the following in your form

```
<input type='hidden'>
```

It is great for passing values without much code.
Or set it as a cookie/session variable as required.

Comment: Well, I use sessions now and they do the trick so thanks for the help, you get accepted :)